# Further split array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have one string array 'oldArray' & want to create a 'newArray' with the elements of 'oldArray' in this way by splitting:

```
String[] oldArray = {"1|14", "10|15", "16|5"};
newArray after spliting oldArary should be like :

newArray = [1,14,10,15,16,5];
```

and println the newArray

Comment: This should be pretty easy if you use `split` method. Any attempts from your end on same?

Comment: `Arrays.stream(oldArray).map(s -> s.split("\\|")).flatMap(Arrays::stream).toArray(String[]::new)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String[] oldArray = {"1|14", "10|15", "16|5"};
    String[] newArray = Arrays.stream(oldArray)
        .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split("\\|")))
        .toArray(String[]::new);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
}
```

output:

```
[1, 14, 10, 15, 16, 5]
```